# Catalog of optimal control problems with analytical solutions

Tags: reference-request, control-theory, optimal-control

Is there any exhaustive reference with a list of optimal control problems with analytical solutions? perhaps starting from the easy ones, like the Brachistochrone and the Zermelo problem, and moving towards more complex ones, with junction points and singular arcs?

Comment: It is unlikely that this exists. Best is to look at books on the topic and check the examples given there.

Comment: How do you like Evans's [An Introduction to Mathematical Optimal Control Theory](https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/control.course.pdf) [PDF]?

Comment: @KBS Thanks for your comment. Yes, I know several books, but I hoped there was a nice collection of multiple academic examples in one place. Thanks though.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo that's actually not too far from my idea, thanks a lot!